# How to avoid Segmentation fault when using N-API?

Tags: c++, node.js, node-addon-api

I'm trying to build a [node-js wrapper](https://github.com/AyyKamp/napi-clip) for the C++ library [Clip](https://github.com/dacap/clip) using the node addon api (N-NAPI). I want to retrive an image from a user's clipboard and pass it to JavaScript in a node.js buffer.

This is what I have tried: (only the relevant portions, rest is [here](https://github.com/AyyKamp/napi-clip/blob/master/src/main.cpp))

```c++
Napi::Object get_image(const Napi::CallbackInfo& args) {
  Napi::Env env = args.Env();

  clip::image img;
  clip::get_image(img);

  clip::image_spec spec = img.spec();

  char *pixels = img.data();
  // since I dont know the length of pixels I use the width * height of the image
  Napi::Buffer<char> img_buffer = Napi::Buffer<char>::New(env, pixels, spec.width * spec.height);
  return img_buffer;
}
```

This compiles just fine but when I try to use it in JavaScript it results in a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Example JS code:

```
const clip = require('bindings')('node_clip_wrapper')
console.log(clip.getImage())
```

How could I resolve this? Please excuse me if I am missing something basic, I am very new to C++ and building node addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `Napi::Buffer::Copy` will be a good solution since copying the underlying data is expensive.

`Napi::Buffer::New`should work as long as you keep the memory alive till JavaScript code is done with the Buffer object. In your case, the data pointed by `pixels` is de-allocated once the function returns.

Also you can use external buffer APIs to manage the memory by yourself:
https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#napi_create_external_arraybuffer

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `Napi::Buffer::Copy` instead of `New`. [Documentation](https://nodejs.github.io/node-addon-api/class_napi_1_1_buffer.html#a1052f42aa5e9f04c16bf3e95f031a54e)

Just Like this:

```c++
Napi::Buffer<char> img_buffer = Napi::Buffer<char>::Copy(env, pixels, spec.width * spec.height);
```